# show an undefined for $scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Here is my code

```
var exchange = angular.module('app', []);
    exchange.controller('ExchangeController', ExchangeController);

    function ExchangeController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.items = [];
        $http
            .get(window.location.origin + "/api/get-item/", {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
            })
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.items = response.data.items;
                console.log($scope.items);
            });

        console.log($scope.items);

    }
```

Here my first console log working properly but second one show undefined. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second written `console.log($scope.items);` should log an empty array to the console. The reason for this is that `$http.get` is performing an asynchronous call. This causes the `then` block's code execution is deferred until the http request completes and allows the rest of the code to continue. If this is your first introduction to asynchrous code I suggest you review [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) - see General Usage. And Promises in Javascript as a whole.

Also consider this [example](https://codepen.io/strake/pen/OxLzbY) I wrote for you on demonstrating async operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `$http` block is running async. When the call reaches your `console.log($scope.items)`, the `http` request may not have returned yet, therefore the item is `undefined`.